# How to read 16 bit integer using QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, qbytearray

I want to read a file with QByteArray but the problem is that it read byte wise and i want array of 16 bit integer. here is my code...

```
 QByteArray fileBuf;
 sprintf_s(filepath, "c:/file.bin");}
 myfile.setFileName(filepath);
 if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
 fileBuf=myfile.readAll();
```

here is the test to find values inside

```
 qint16 z;
 for(int test =0; test < 5 ; test++)
 {
  z= (fileBuf[i]);
 qDebug()<< i<<"is="<<z;
```

result:

```
0 is= -88 (// in binary// 1111 1111 1010 1000)
1 is= -2   (// in binary// 1111 1111 1111 1110)
2 is= -64 
3 is= -3 
4 is= 52
```

these are because of 8 bit array i need 16 bit i,e.. at  value at 0 = -344 (//binary// 1111 11110 1010 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QFile myfile;
myfile.setFileName("c:/file.bin");
if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;

QDataStream data(&myfile);
data.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
QVector<qint16> result;
while(!data.atEnd()) {
    qint16 x;
    data >> x;
    result.append(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the constData (or data) pointers from QByteArray and do a casting to qint16:

```
QByteArray fileBuf;
const char * data=fileBuf.constData();
const qint16 * data16=reinterpret_cast<const qint16 *>(data);
int len=fileBuf.size()/(sizeof(qint16));  //Get the new len, since size() returns the number of 
                                          //bytes, and not the number of 16bit words.

//Iterate over all the words:
for (int i=0;i<len;++i) {
    //qint16 z=*data16;  //Get the value
    //data16++;          //Update the pointer to point to the next value

    //EDIT: Both lines above can be replaced with:
    qint16 z=data16[i]        

    //Use z....
    qDebug()<< i<<" is= "<<z;
}
```

Comment: thanks that shows correct result but I am in need of array to use like data16[i] because m using qwtspectrogram to plot. is there any way to arrange the data in (data16[i]) format...

Comment: You can use data16 as an array... the arrays behaves as pointers. I have updated the answer to show you